# How to get Id after data is created in React (Next JS) and Apollo

Tags: reactjs, graphql, next.js, apollo, apollo-client

I'm trying to make the place order in the ecommerce website I'm trying to make for my personal project. I wanted after I created the data or input the data I have made I get that `Id` and Redirect it to the `orders/[id]` then the `Id`.

### Here is my code:

---

```
import React, { useContext, useState } from "react";
import { FETCH_USER_QUERY } from "../util/graphql/Queries";
import { useMutation, useQuery } from "@apollo/react-hooks";
import { AuthContext } from "../context/auth";
import { CartContext } from "../context/cart/CartContext";
import { Form, Button } from "semantic-ui-react";
import { CREATE_ORDER_MUTATION } from "../util/graphql/Mutations";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";

export default function Checkout() {
  const router = useRouter();

  const [cartItems, setCartItems] = useContext(CartContext);
  const [paymentMethod, setPaymentMethod] = useState("");
  const [address, setAddress] = useState("");

  const [createOrder, { data, loading }] = useMutation(CREATE_ORDER_MUTATION);

  const qty = cartItems.map(({ quantity }) => {
    return quantity;
  });

  const cartItemId = cartItems.map(({ id }) => {
    return id;
  });

  function onSubmit() {
    createOrder({
      variables: {
        qty: qty[0],

        products: cartItemId[0],
        paymentMethod: paymentMethod,
        address: address,
      },
    })
      .then(() => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          const { createOrder: order } = { ...data };
          console.log(order?.id);
        }, 500);
      })
  }

  return (
    <>
      <Form onSubmit={onSubmit} className={loading ? "loading" : ""}>
        <h2>Create a Main Category:</h2>
        <Form.Field>
          <Form.Input
            placeholder="Please Enter Address"
            name="address"
            label="Address: "
            onChange={(event) => {
              setAddress(event.target.value);
            }}
            value={address}
          />
          <label>Status: </label>
          <select
            name="category"
            className="form-control"
            onChange={(event) => {
              setPaymentMethod(event.target.value);
            }}
          >
            <option value="Cash On Delivery">Cash On Delivery</option>
            <option value="PayPal">PayPal</option>
            <option value="GCash">GCash</option>
          </select>
          <br />

          <Button type="submit" color="teal">
            Submit
          </Button>
        </Form.Field>
      </Form>
    </>
  );
}
```

But after I submitted my inputted data the log returns me `undefined`, but when I input data again and submit it gives me the previous id of that data. Is there any way to do this? If you don't understand what I mean please let me know I'll explain in the comments, or if you need any code I could give it to you I will be transparent as I can

Comment: You should look at simplifying the onSubmit function by using async/await instead of promises/then.. it'll be much easier to read.

Comment: Hello thanks for answering, I'll try to apply it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to return the `res` parameter from your *promise*. It should look something like this:

```
.then((res) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    const { createOrder: order } = { ...res };
    console.log(order?.id);
  }, 500);
})
```

Comment: Hello thanks for answering, I'm sorry but it still returns undefined

Comment: Can you `console.log(data)` as the first thing in `setTimeout`?

Comment: Yes please wait

Comment: Another thing, shouldn't `then` return something like `res` which contains the data? Can you try adding that to the function and logging it?

Comment: Oh my gosh thank you so much it should return something like res I forgot to input it, It really worked thank you again

Comment: Yes saw it I marked as the accepted answer and upvoted it thanks again for ur time and help really appreciate it :)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `SetTimeOut()`, you can simply use the `onCompleted()` function in Apollo graphql to perform anything whenever the mutation is successfully completed.

```
  const [createOrder, { data, loading }] = useMutation(CREATE_ORDER_MUTATION, {
       variables: {
    
          },
       
      onCompleted(data) {
          console.log(data) // this is log all queries from the mutation including the ID you need
        // whatever you want to do when the mutation is successful
        
           router.push({
           pathname: '/any-page',
       query: {CartID: data.cart_id}, // check the console.log to see how the ID is returned });       
 }});
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is being caused by stale closure. The object reference of `data` at the time of setTimeout being pushed into the callback queue is an older one. Hence the value was never refreshed. You need to get the newer value by dispatch the action on the same previous state or using a useRef.

Comment: Hello thanks for answering I understand what you are explaining, could you please make an example with my data if possible? Thanks again